# How do I get the client Remote Port number in a Django?

Tags: django

I know I can use `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the client's IP in my django view function.
However, I have no idea how to get the client remote port number.

For example, you can see your own remote port number on the site below:

https://www.myip.com/

[Remote Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR1mI.png)

here is sample of view.py:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
        gelenIleti = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if gelenIleti:
            ip = gelenIleti.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            portNumarasi = request.META['SERVER_PORT']
        logger.info(' ' + 'LOG KAYDI :' + ' ' + ' KULLANICI : ' + request.user.username + ' ' + ' IP : ' + ip + ' ' + ' SERVER PORT : ' + portNumarasi)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: what do you want to use this port number for?

Comment: It is mandatory to keep ip and port number information in our country.(Turkey)

Comment: @sefaseker, what Django  version are you using?

Comment: I am using Django 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the IP and PORT through `WSGIRequest` connected socket.

**Django 1.11**:

```
sock = request._stream.stream._sock
client_ip, port = sock.getpeername()
```

**Django 2.1**:

```
sock = request._stream.stream.raw._sock
client_ip, port = sock.getpeername()
```

**Django 2.2 and 3.1**:

```
sock = request._stream.stream.stream.raw._sock
client_ip, port = sock.getpeername()
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    sock = request._stream.stream.stream.raw._sock
    client_ip, port = sock.getpeername()

    logger.info(' LOG KAYDI : KULLANICI : %s IP : %s SERVER PORT : %s' % (request.user.username, client_ip, port))
```

Comment: very grateful for your attention but i don't know how to use these codes.

Comment: I tried it right now and it works. I searched a lot, but your answer solved the problem. I'm very much obliged to you. If you come to Turkey, I can buy you a coffee :)

Comment: Hi sometimes I get ```AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'stream'```. Any idea how I could solve that?

Comment: @Gabriel, which Django version you are using?

Comment: @NKSM I am using Django 4.0.6. It was ok for one user but when switching users it have this exception. Sometime works but most of the time this exception. I am using ```sock = request._stream.stream.stream.raw._sock```

Comment: I managed to get it from request.META.get('REMOTE_PORT') though you need to use nginx or werkzeug